# How to setup sublime text 2 (ST2) for latex

Tags: sublime-text

I just started using Sublime Text 2 and I want to use it to compile latex files. I found this tutorial from the official repository (my guess) :

```
https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#readme
```

But my problem is that I don't know where to find the file `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` that it describes in the tutorial:

> You also need to edit the file `LaTeX.sublime-settings` in the User directory to make sure that the configuration reflects your preferred TeX distribution. Open that file and scroll down to the section titled "Platform settings." Look at the block for your OS, namely "linux". Within that block, verify that the "texpath" setting is correct. Notice that this must include $PATH somewhere, or things will not work.

What should this file have? I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

P.S. My user directory has no such file

Comment: How did you install `LaTeXTools`? Install it through `Package Control`: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation . and then modify `LaTeXTools Preferences.sublime-settings` - https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/LaTeXTools%20Preferences.sublime-settings.OLD . Put a copy of this file in your User directory and then customize.

Comment: do I name the file `LaTexToolsPreferences.sublime-settings` ?

Comment: @HarishKumar to be clear, do you need to create the file(s)? The docs seem to imply they're already there, but alas, no.

Comment: @NickT `LaTexToolsPreferences.sublime-settings.OLD`. The link is in the previous comment. You have to remove `.OLD`